# Any Eclipse editor plugins for MVC classes?

Tags: model-view-controller, eclipse-plugin, tabs

Is there a good Eclipse editor plugin that would open the view, model and controller class files in one editor with each file having its own tab? E.g. if I have classes FooView, FooModel and FooController and opened one of them, it would open an editor with all of those 3 classes (with an "internal" tab for each of them).

I have used the now discontinued Wicket Bench plugin (which opens related files on their own tabs based on the file extension) when working with the Wicket framework and would love to have something similar when working with MVC classes. (Since the plugin's page is now infested with spam, the only proper screenshot I could find is in the SVN repository: http://svn.laughingpanda.org/svn/wicket-bench/trunk/wicket-bench/docs/wicket_editor.jpg)

I was thinking of writing a plugin like this but would of course love to hear it already exists. I've tried to find one but I guess none exist or my searching skills just need some polishing... However, I think this kind of editor would also help with this problem:
[Eclipse PDT Differentiating file name tabs for MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409778/eclipse-pdt-differentiating-file-name-tabs-for-mvc)

Thank you for any tips.